# Android Espresso Tests for phone and tablet

Tags: android, android-espresso

My setup:
- Android App with Phone and Tablet Version
- I am using Android Espresso for UI-Tests (now only for phone version, with phone at buildagent)

What I want to do:
- Now I want Espresso to distinguish between tests for phone and tablet
- So Test A should be only execute by a tablet, Test B should only be executed by a phone and Test C both
- Tests should be executable via gradle task

Comment: Are U using Android Studio?

Comment: Would be really cool if there were some annotations, like `@Phone` and `@Tablet`, or `@DeviceConfig(smallestWidth=480)`, so that you can annotate your test methods with these annotations and depending of your device type, to execute or not a particular test method. This does not exist yet, but would be nice to have... just saying...

Answer (score 19):

Three options, all of which are executable via `gradlew connectedAndroidTest` or custom gradle tasks:

## 1. Use `org.junit.Assume`

From [Assumptions with assume - junit-team/junit Wiki - Github](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Assumptions-with-assume):

> The default JUnit runner treats tests with failing assumptions as ignored. Custom runners may behave differently.

Unfortunately, the `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4` (`com.android.support.test:runner:0.2`) runner treats failing assumptions as failed tests.

Once this behavior is fixed, the following would work (see Option 3 below for `isScreenSw600dp()` source):

**Phone only: all test methods in the class**

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        assumeTrue(!isScreenSw600dp());
        // other setup
    }
```

**Specific test methods**

```
    @Test
    public void testA() {
        assumeTrue(!isScreenSw600dp());
        // test for phone only
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testB() {
        assumeTrue(isScreenSw600dp());
        // test for tablet only
    }
```

---

## 2. Use a custom JUnit Rule

From [A JUnit Rule to Conditionally Ignore Tests](http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/11/18/a-junit-rule-to-conditionally-ignore-tests/):

> This led us to creating a *ConditionalIgnore* annotation and a corresponding rule to hook it into the JUnit runtime. The thing is simple and best explained with an example:

```
public class SomeTest {
  @Rule
  public ConditionalIgnoreRule rule = new ConditionalIgnoreRule();

  @Test
  @ConditionalIgnore( condition = NotRunningOnWindows.class )
  public void testFocus() {
    // ...
  }
}

public class NotRunningOnWindows implements IgnoreCondition {
  public boolean isSatisfied() {
    return !System.getProperty( "os.name" ).startsWith( "Windows" );
  }
}
```

`ConditionalIgnoreRule` code here: [JUnit rule to conditionally ignore test cases](https://gist.github.com/rherrmann/7447571).

This approach can be easily modified to implement the `isScreenSw600dp()` method in Option 3 below.

---

## 3. Use conditionals in the test methods

This is the least elegant option, particularly because entirely skipped tests will be reported as passed, but it's very easy to implement.  Here's a full sample test class to get you started:

```
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.assertion.ViewAssertions.matches;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isDisplayed;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class DeleteMeTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    private MainActivity mActivity;
    private boolean mIsScreenSw600dp;

    public DeleteMeTest() {
        super(MainActivity.class);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        injectInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
        mActivity = this.getActivity();
        mIsScreenSw600dp = isScreenSw600dp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mActivity.finish();
    }

    @Test
    public void testPreconditions() {
        onView(withId(R.id.your_view_here))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        if (!mIsScreenSw600dp) {
            // test for phone only
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testB() {
        if (mIsScreenSw600dp) {
            // test for tablet only
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testC() {
        if (mIsScreenSw600dp) {
            // test for tablet only
        } else {
            // test for phone only
        }
        
        // test for both phone and tablet
    }

    private boolean isScreenSw600dp() {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        float widthDp = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        float heightDp = displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        float screenSw = Math.min(widthDp, heightDp);
        return screenSw >= 600;
    }
}
```

Comment: Still with `com.android.support.test:runner:0.5` assumptions are treated as failing tests.

Comment: I'm running runner 0.5 and espresso 2.2.2 and failed assumptions are marked as ignored, at least in the android studio runner.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is bit old but thought to post as this is kinda simpler way.
So just put a Boolean value for targeted screen size -
for ex `values-sw600dp.xml` for tablet and `values.xml` for phone. 
Put a Boolean value in both
for example in `values.xml` -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="tablet">false</bool>
</resources>
```

and in `values-sw600.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="tablet">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Then in Test class use this to get resource value-

```
Context targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
targetContext.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.tablet);
Boolean isTabletUsed = targetContext.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.tablet);
```